# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modules' in tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, compiler-errors, ubuntu-16.04, spyder

I have been learning tensorflow, and until now everything was fine. I have even used the GPU to do some calculations with tensorflow. But suddenly I have the following error when running the **import tensorflow as tf** command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-41389fad42b5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "/home/diego/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *

  File "/home/diego/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_tensorflow
```

It is very easy to fix, I just reset the console. But it is very anoying because I need to reset the console each time after I run the script. (Even if the script is just **"import tensorflow as tf"**)

when I run the whole script with F5 I got a different error, even if the only command is **import tensorflow as tf**. 
I'm running the script in spyder 2.7 Python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

```
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
      execfile(filename, namespace)

    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
      builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

    File "/home/diego/Desktop/Diego/Trial-Job/Code/pointnet/test2tf.py", line 7, in <module>
      import tensorflow as tf

    File "/home/diego/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
      from tensorflow.python import *

    File "/home/diego/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
      from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *

    File "/home/diego/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
      from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor

    File "/home/diego/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
      __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)

    File "/home/diego/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
      from pkg_resources.extern import six

    File "/home/diego/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 44, in load_module
      mod = sys.modules[extant]

  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modules'
```

Thank you.

Comment: The problem seems to be spyder, I don't have any error if I work on the console.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the problem is on the wildcard import

```
from tensorflow.python import *
```

As it says on the [Pep 8 Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

> Wildcard imports (from module import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools (...)

Have you tried to import each used module by name and remove the wildcard import?

Comment: But I never imported anything explicitly with a wildcard, I just did **import tensorflow as tf**, "like everybody else", that wildcard is used implicitly. I'm new to tensorflow so any extra information is helpful. Anyway, I will try your method, Thank you.